# values not showing correctly in dropdown

Tags: android

i've set it so my items from a csv show in a dropdown list, but when I click on the list on my phone it shows values like `[Ljava.lang.String;@427fa7co` or another number code.

but when I click on one of them, the correct name shows up on the display of the dropdown. just not in the actual list.

Main activity:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class create extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();
        MyListAdapter adapter=new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow,R.id.txtid, itemList);
        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



        //ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream){
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read(){

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main",e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }



}
```

Mylistadapter.java - I think the problem might be in here

```
   import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.String;


public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {
    int groupid;
    List<String> items;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, List<String> items) {
        super(context, vg, id, (List<String[]>) items);
        this.context = context;
        groupid = vg;
        this.items = items;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textid;
        public TextView textname;

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        {





            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
                viewHolder.textname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            // Fill data in the drop down.
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            String row = items.get(position);
            //holder.textid.setText(row[0]); prints aisle number, dont need

            holder.textname.setText(row[1]);


            return rowView;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and highlight the places in your code where you think the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spinner` uses `ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView` instead of `ArrayAdapter.getView` iirc. The signature is the same, the method is different. Change from

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

to

```
 @Override
 public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

Comment: Your question was different when I first answered it. Why are you reading your CSV in a List<String[]> and not on a List<String>? What's the content of your CSV?

Comment: Oh,..in my csv I've got two columns, one has numbers and the other has item names.

Comment: And how would you like to display them? If you click on an item what would you expect to happen?

Comment: I would expect the selected item to be shown on the spinner's front, just like how most dropdowns work. For now, I am ignoring the numbers I have in the csv.

Comment: Could you post couple of entries of your CSV?

Comment: 1,Coffee
1,Drinking Chocolate
2,Energy Drinks
2,Water
2,Soft Drinks
2,Juice
3,Canned Fruit
3,Desserts
3,Spreads
3,Milk Products
4,Cereals (each item on a different line, the formatting on comments is odd)

Comment: Then the changes are minimal. The task you are using to read the CSV, should return a List<String>, and instead of doing `resultList.add(row);`  you do `resultList.add(row[1]);`. You will have to change your adapter to accept a `List<String>` instead of a `List<String[]>` as well

Comment: I have changed that, but getting an error: 'error: array required, but String found
' this occurs at line  '            holder.textname.setText(row[1]);'. I have updated my java code  for activity and Adapter in my above post.

Comment: It is the `extends ArrayAdapter<String>` instead of `extends ArrayAdapter<String []>`. `row[1]` should just be `row`

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help! (I can only award bounty in 13 hours)

Comment: No worries. I am glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

The problem actually is that when you adapt the List<> to the ListView, each item on the List is an Array on its own, so, as there is no exact text to display, it displays

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@427fa7co
```

Evidence? try to excecute:

```
Log.d(list[0].toString());
```

and you should get the exact same

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@427fa7co
```

Solution: 
Simplest: in case you dont need to have an List of Arrays ( N x M ) just use `List<String>`

Intermediate: 
Try to create a new Object Class and make a property String[], Override the toString() Method to get the exact text you want to be displayed

Expert: not actually harder that the previous but should be the best practice
Create a new Object Class and make the properties you actually need, (example id, name, address etc..) Override the toString() Method to get the exact text you want to be displayed example

```
@Override
public string toString()
{
  return this.name;
}
```